# Split a number into 4 specified parts thats togetter the same number

Tags: php

Need to split a number for example 5000 into 4 parts in a array

```
$total = 5000;
```

Array should look like:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 500
    [1] => 250
    [2] => 250
    [3] => 4000
)
```

So if the user enters 600 for example i need a array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 500
    [1] => 100
    [2] =>  0
    [3] =>  0
)
```

this is what i got, but im sure there is a better way. When i enter 600 for example i get 2 undefined offsets

```
$total_spidex = 5000;

        $price_total = array();

        for($i=1; $i<=$total_spidex; $i++)
        {
            if($i <= 500)
            {
                $price_total[1][] = $i;
            }       
            elseif($i >500 && $i <= 750)
            {
                $price_total[2][] = $i;         
            }
            elseif($i >750 && $i <= 1000)
            {
                $price_total[3][] = $i;         
            }
            elseif($i >1000)
            {
                $price_total[4][] = $i;         
            }

        }

        $sum = 0;

        $sum = (count($price_total[1]) * 12) + (count($price_total[2]) * 11) + (count($price_total[3]) * 10) + (count($price_total[4]) * 9);
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: How i get it in a array as in the second code block

Comment: In your first statement you want to split a number in 4 parts and in your second example you have split it in 2 parts. This is quite ambiguous.

Comment: Im sorry if its not clear but it depends on what the user enters.

Comment: and what is the rule for splitting? is it arbitrary?

Comment: If the number is over 1000 it has to be 4 parts. First part 500 second 250 third 250 fourth whats left over. If number is under 1000 lets say 850 first part 500 again second 250 third has to be 100 then en fourth emtpy or 0. I updated my question

Comment: 1) Your code puts the value of i in the four cells of your array instead of putting number fraction. 2) Assuming you have a cake weighting 1kg on a table, if you slice it in one big part and a smaller one, put the big one in bag n°1, what is the weight of the remaining part ? 1kg ? Obviously no : you'll have to substract something from 1kg to know the weight of the remaining part on the table, that you can slice again and put one bits in bag n°2... Are you going to count each gram one by one, or just do some math ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$number = 5000;             // initial number
$limit = 1000;              // limit for chunks

$parts = array(
   array(500, 250, 250, 0), // dividers for $number >= $limit, 0 - the rest of #
   array(500, 250, 100, 0)  // dividers for $number < $limit
);

$result = array();          // array with results

$blocks = $number < $limit; // which set of dividers to use

foreach($parts[$blocks] as $divider) 
   if ($number > $divider && $divider > 0) {
      $result[] = $divider; // if number is larger than divider, add divider
      $number -= $divider;  // subtract divider from number
   }
   else {
      $result[] = $number;   // otherwise add the number
      $number = 0;           // and set it to zero
   }

var_dump($result);           // output result
```

No nested loops, extra conditions and you can easily modify and add more numerical values into `$parts` array. If there is no difference between the parts above and below the `$limit`, the code will be even more simple (may be I did not understand you correctly from comments)

```
$number = 500;

$parts = array(500, 250, 250, 0);

$result = array();

foreach($parts as $divider) 
   if ($number > $divider && $divider > 0) {
      $result[] = $divider;
      $number -= $divider;
   }
   else
   {
      $result[] = $number;
      $number = 0;
   }

var_dump($result);
```

Output is exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

There you go, should be expresive by itself

```
<?php

function splitNumber($number)
{
    if ($number >= 1000)
    {
        $t[0] = 500;
        $t[1] = $t[2] = 250;
        $t[3] = $number - ($t[0]+$t[1]+$t[2]);
    }
    else if ($number > 750 && $number < 1000)
    {
        $t[0] = 500;
        $t[1] = 250;
        $t[2] = $number - ($t[0]+$t[1]);
        $t[3] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        $t[0] = $number;
        $t[1] = $t[2] = $t[3] = 0;
    }

    return $t;
 }

// Some results

$my_number = splitNumber(768); 
// Array ( [0] => 500 [1] => 250 [2] => 18 [3] => 0 )
$my_number = splitNumber(1953); 
// Array ( [0] => 500 [2] => 250 [1] => 250 [3] => 953 )
$my_number = splitNumber(821); 
// Array ( [0] => 500 [1] => 250 [2] => 71 [3] => 0 )
$my_number = splitNumber(2546);
// Array ( [0] => 500 [2] => 250 [1] => 250 [3] => 1546 )

// and so on ...

?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please mark it as a solution if it fit your needs. And glad that helped ;) oups, saw it was marked on post above ;)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way...

```
$total_spidex = 5000;
$price_total = array();
$count = $total_spidex;

if ($count > 500){
$count -= 500;
$price_total[0] = 500;

    if ($count > 250){
    $count -= 250;
    $price_total[1] = 250;

        if ($count > 250){
        $count -= 250;
        $price_total[2] = 250;

            if ($count > 750){
            $count -= 750;
            $price_total[3] = 750;
            $price_total[4] = $count;
            }
            else $price_total[3] = $count;

        }
        else $price_total[2] = $count;

    }
    else $price_total[1] = $count;

}
else $price_total[0] = $count;
```

Comment: Try to avoid pasting in code blobs for answers. Help out the OP by explaining what the code does or where their error is.

Comment: @atmacola : Even better chatting with OP in his post before answering, trying to lead him to find out slightly by himself - with good questions, comparisons, etc. And don't worry, I've just been taught not to post code like you did in another very fresh easy question myself. Those who does this are in fact slowly killing SO. Now, giving answers on a silver plate is the last thing I'll do for simple to average level of difficulty. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// your code goes here
$answer = array();
$value = 600;

if($value > 500){
    array_push($answer, 500);
    $value = $value-500;
}
else {
    array_push($answer, $value);
    $value = 0;
}
for ($i = 0; $i<2; $i++){
    if ($value >250){
        array_push($answer, 250);
        $value = $value - 250;
    }
    else {
        array_push($answer, $value);
        $value = 0;
    }
}

array_push($answer, $value);
print_r($answer);
?>
```

Here you go, based on your comments, this is I wrote.

Comment: Here I haven't used your variable rather than some simple variables. You can replace them at your choice.